# PDO SQL insert syntax issue

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I'm trying to get my page to insert multiple rows into my database at once. All info comes from a previous page. When a certain coordinate is entered, the row isn't saved.

While testing, just Alpha gets a coordinate that differs from the excluded coordinate.

When I run the code, I get the following error:

```
SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1064 You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near ')' at line 2
```

This is my code:

```
try {
                        $conn = new PDO("mysql:host=$servername;dbname=$database", $username, $password);

                        $dag = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_GET['dag']);
                        $tijd = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_GET['tijd']);

                        $wgs_coordinaat_x_alpha = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_GET["x_alpha"]);
                        $wgs_coordinaat_y_alpha = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_GET["y_alpha"]);
                        $wgs_coordinaat_x_bravo = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_GET["x_bravo"]);
                        $wgs_coordinaat_y_bravo = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_GET["y_bravo"]);
                        $wgs_coordinaat_x_charlie = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_GET["x_charlie"]);
                        $wgs_coordinaat_y_charlie = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_GET["y_charlie"]);
                        $wgs_coordinaat_x_delta = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_GET["x_delta"]);
                        $wgs_coordinaat_y_delta = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_GET["y_delta"]);
                        $wgs_coordinaat_x_echo = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_GET["x_echo"]);
                        $wgs_coordinaat_y_echo = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_GET["y_echo"]);
                        $wgs_coordinaat_x_foxtrot = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_GET["x_foxtrot"]);
                        $wgs_coordinaat_y_foxtrot = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_GET["y_foxtrot"]);

                        // set the PDO error mode to exception
                        $conn->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);

                        // begin the transaction
                        $conn->beginTransaction();
                        // our SQL statements
                        if ($wgs_coordinaat_x_alpha == "47.9747674834") {}
                            else {
                                $conn->exec("INSERT INTO markers (id, type, dag, tijd, deelgebied, lat, lng) 
                                VALUES (NULL, 'Hint', '$dag', '$tijd', 'Alpha', '$wgs_coordinaat_x_alpha', '$wgs_coordinaat_y_alpha')");
                            }
                        if ($wgs_coordinaat_x_bravo == "47.9747674834") {}
                            else {
                                $conn->exec("INSERT INTO markers (id, type, dag, tijd, deelgebied, lat, lng) 
                                VALUES (NULL, 'Hint', '$dag', '$tijd', 'Bravo', '$wgs_coordinaat_x_bravo', '$wgs_coordinaat_y_bravo'))");
                            }
                        if ($wgs_coordinaat_x_charlie == "47.9747674834") {}
                            else {
                                $conn->exec("INSERT INTO markers (id, type, dag, tijd, deelgebied, lat, lng) 
                                VALUES (NULL, 'Hint', '$dag', '$tijd', 'Charlie', '$wgs_coordinaat_x_charlie', '$wgs_coordinaat_y_charlie')");
                            }
                        if ($wgs_coordinaat_x_delta == "47.9747674834") {}
                            else {
                                $conn->exec("INSERT INTO markers (id, type, dag, tijd, deelgebied, lat, lng) 
                                VALUES (NULL, 'Hint', '$dag', '$tijd', 'Delta', '$wgs_coordinaat_x_delta', '$wgs_coordinaat_y_delta')");
                            }
                        if ($wgs_coordinaat_x_echo == "47.9747674834") {}
                            else {
                                $conn->exec("INSERT INTO markers (id, type, dag, tijd, deelgebied, lat, lng) 
                                VALUES (NULL, 'Hint', '$dag', '$tijd', 'Echo', '$wgs_coordinaat_x_echo', '$wgs_coordinaat_y_echo')");
                            }
                        if ($wgs_coordinaat_x_foxtrot == "47.9747674834") {}
                            else {
                                $conn->exec("INSERT INTO markers (id, type, dag, tijd, deelgebied, lat, lng) 
                                VALUES (NULL, 'Hint', '$dag', '$tijd', 'Foxtrot', '$wgs_coordinaat_x_foxtrot', '$wgs_coordinaat_y_foxtrot')");
                            }   
                        // commit the transaction
                        $conn->commit();
                        echo "Hint succesvol toegevoegd!";
                        }
                    catch(PDOException $e)
                        {
                        // roll back the transaction if something failed
                        $conn->rollback();
                        echo "Opes! Iets is fout gegaan: " . $e->getMessage();
                        }

                    $conn = null;
```

I'm out of ideas. Thanks!

Comment: This statement `$conn->exec("INSERT INTO markers (id, type, dag, tijd, deelgebied, lat, lng) VALUES (NULL, 'Hint', '$dag', '$tijd', 'Bravo', '$wgs_coordinaat_x_bravo', '$wgs_coordinaat_y_bravo'))");` looks like it has an extra `)`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
try {
    $conn = new PDO("mysql:host=$servername;dbname=$database", $username, $password);

    $dag = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_GET['dag']);
    $tijd = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_GET['tijd']);

    $wgs_coordinaat_x_alpha = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_GET["x_alpha"]);
    $wgs_coordinaat_y_alpha = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_GET["y_alpha"]);
    $wgs_coordinaat_x_bravo = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_GET["x_bravo"]);
    $wgs_coordinaat_y_bravo = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_GET["y_bravo"]);
    $wgs_coordinaat_x_charlie = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_GET["x_charlie"]);
    $wgs_coordinaat_y_charlie = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_GET["y_charlie"]);
    $wgs_coordinaat_x_delta = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_GET["x_delta"]);
    $wgs_coordinaat_y_delta = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_GET["y_delta"]);
    $wgs_coordinaat_x_echo = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_GET["x_echo"]);
    $wgs_coordinaat_y_echo = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_GET["y_echo"]);
    $wgs_coordinaat_x_foxtrot = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_GET["x_foxtrot"]);
    $wgs_coordinaat_y_foxtrot = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_GET["y_foxtrot"]);

    // set the PDO error mode to exception
    $conn->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);

    // begin the transaction
    $conn->beginTransaction();

    // our SQL statements
    if ($wgs_coordinaat_x_alpha != "47.9747674834") {
        $conn->exec("INSERT INTO markers (id, type, dag, tijd, deelgebied, lat, lng) VALUES (NULL, 'Hint', '$dag', '$tijd', 'Alpha', '$wgs_coordinaat_x_alpha', '$wgs_coordinaat_y_alpha')");
    }
    if ($wgs_coordinaat_x_bravo != "47.9747674834") {
        $conn->exec("INSERT INTO markers (id, type, dag, tijd, deelgebied, lat, lng) VALUES (NULL, 'Hint', '$dag', '$tijd', 'Bravo', '$wgs_coordinaat_x_bravo', '$wgs_coordinaat_y_bravo')");
    }
    if ($wgs_coordinaat_x_charlie != "47.9747674834") {
        $conn->exec("INSERT INTO markers (id, type, dag, tijd, deelgebied, lat, lng) VALUES (NULL, 'Hint', '$dag', '$tijd', 'Charlie', '$wgs_coordinaat_x_charlie', '$wgs_coordinaat_y_charlie')");
    }
    if ($wgs_coordinaat_x_delta != "47.9747674834") {
        $conn->exec("INSERT INTO markers (id, type, dag, tijd, deelgebied, lat, lng) VALUES (NULL, 'Hint', '$dag', '$tijd', 'Delta', '$wgs_coordinaat_x_delta', '$wgs_coordinaat_y_delta')");
    }
    if ($wgs_coordinaat_x_echo != "47.9747674834") {
        $conn->exec("INSERT INTO markers (id, type, dag, tijd, deelgebied, lat, lng) VALUES (NULL, 'Hint', '$dag', '$tijd', 'Echo', '$wgs_coordinaat_x_echo', '$wgs_coordinaat_y_echo')");
    }
    if ($wgs_coordinaat_x_foxtrot != "47.9747674834") {
        $conn->exec("INSERT INTO markers (id, type, dag, tijd, deelgebied, lat, lng) VALUES (NULL, 'Hint', '$dag', '$tijd', 'Foxtrot', '$wgs_coordinaat_x_foxtrot', '$wgs_coordinaat_y_foxtrot')");
    }

    // commit the transaction
    $conn->commit();
    echo "Hint succesvol toegevoegd!";
}
catch(PDOException $e)
{
    // roll back the transaction if something failed
    $conn->rollback();
    echo "Opes! Iets is fout gegaan: " . $e->getMessage();
}

$conn = null;
```

Double closing brackets on line:

```
VALUES (NULL, 'Hint', '$dag', '$tijd', 'Bravo', '$wgs_coordinaat_x_bravo', '$wgs_coordinaat_y_bravo'))");
```

I switched your if statements to use `!=` and by that we got rid of extra `else` statements. Also, since your coords (`47.9747674834`) are the same in all statements, consider caching it in a variable.

Comment: Thanks for your advise. Using != would make the code more efficient and placing the caching the coordinate would make sense.

Comment: Is this solution working?

Comment: Yes. The main issue was the double bracket. I was completely focused on the Alpha statement, that I didn't notice my mistake further down the code.

Comment: Then it would be really nice if you could upvote and accept as the correct answer.

Answer (score 1):

Double brackets in this line:

```
VALUES (NULL, 'Hint', '$dag', '$tijd', 'Bravo', '$wgs_coordinaat_x_bravo', '$wgs_coordinaat_y_bravo'))");
```

Answer (score 0):

As others have stated, you have two closing parentheses in your SQL on the line where you insert the Bravo coordinates.

But I have to comment on some other best practices, not related to your syntax error.

You should use query parameters instead of interpolating variables into your SQL string. This is easier and safer, because it helps you avoid syntax errors like you did.

Also, you're mixing mysqli functions with PDO.

Here's how I might write this code:

```
try {
    $conn = new PDO("mysql:host=$servername;dbname=$database", $username, $password);

    // set the PDO error mode to exception
    $conn->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);

   if (isset($_GET['dag']) {
       $dag = $_GET['dag'];
   } else {
       die("dag is verplicht");
   }
   if (isset($_GET['tijd']) {
       $tijd = $_GET['tijd'];
   } else {
       die("tijd is verplicht");
   }

    // begin the transaction
    $conn->beginTransaction();

    // our SQL statements
    $stmt = $conn->prepare("INSERT INTO markers
        SET type='Hint', dag=:dag, tijd=:tijd, deelgebied='Alpha', lat=:lat, lng=:lng");

    foreach (['alpha', 'bravo', 'charlie', 'delta', 'echo', 'foxtrot'] as $coord) {

        if (isset($_GET["x_$coord"]) && $_GET["x_$coord"] != "47.9747674834") {
            $stmt->execute([
                'dag'=>$dag,
                'tijd'=>$tijd,
                'lat'=>$_GET["x_$coord"],
                'lng'=>$_GET["y_$coord"]
            ]);
        }
    }

    // commit the transaction
    $conn->commit();
    echo "Hint succesvol toegevoegd!";
}
catch(PDOException $e)
{
    // roll back the transaction if something failed
    $conn->rollback();
    echo "Opes! Iets is fout gegaan: " . $e->getMessage();
}

$conn = null;
```